# Подскажите ошибку при сборке проекта на react native?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, native

Ошибка

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(26.0.1) from [com.android.support:ap                                     pcompat-v7:26.0.1] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35
        is also present at [com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0] AndroidManifest.xml:28:13-35 value=(26.1.0).
        Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:26:9-28:38 to over                                     ride.
```

код build.gradle в app/build.gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-orientation')
    compile project(':react-native-adjust')
    compile project(':react-native-onesignal')
    compile project(':react-native-video')
    compile project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    compile project(':react-native-spinkit')
    compile project(':react-native-appodeal')
    compile project(':react-native-push-notification')
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1"
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:11.8.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-base-support:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:+'
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter()
    maven {
        url 'https://maven.google.com/'
        url "https://adcolony.bintray.com/AdColony"
    }

    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            force 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.28.0'
        }
    }
}
```

Нашел очень много ответов на этом сайте, но ничего не помогло.

если ставлю compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
вроде все ок, но опять спотыкается на этом

```
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:transformDexArchiveWithDexMergerForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/internal/zzchn;
```

В чем проблема? Обычно редко задаю вопросы здесь, но здесь уже безысходность

Comment: На русском stackoverflow принято задавать вопросы на русском языке. Исправьте вопрос переведя его на русский

Comment: У вас из дубликат класса `com/google/android/gms/internal/zzchn`, проверьте дерево зависимостей, откуда берется.

Answer (score 0):

Решил вопрос: https://medium.com/@suchydan/how-to-solve-google-play-services-version-collision-in-gradle-dependencies-ef086ae5c75f#.9l0u84y9t

Ошибки были в дубликатах, как написал Евгений Кривенья